# How to get the sum of column's data in Yii using query?

Tags: php, yii

I want the SUM of data available in the particular column using the Yii query.
Here is the code:

```
$resource_cnt = Resources::model()->findAll(array(
     'select'=>'prj_id, SUM(amount) as amt',
     'condition'=>'prj_id=:prj_id',
     'params'=>array(':prj_id'=>$_POST['Resources']['prj_id']))
);
```

I tried using the query above. But it did not get the SUM of `amt` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "correct" thing to do it Yii, if you want it nicely do in the model, is to
declare a property in `Resources` called `amt`.
Then it should work with your query. Yii only populates those atrributes from a select query, which it can find in the model.

```
class Resources.... {

  public $amt;
...

  public yourFunction() {

    $resource_cnt = Resources::model()->findAll(array(
      'select'=>'prj_id, SUM(amount) as amt',
      'condition'=>'prj_id=:prj_id',
      'params'=>array(':prj_id'=>$_POST['Resources']['prj_id']))
    );

    echo $resource_cnt->amt;
  }

...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I modified a query using the CreateCommand. Through that I got the sum of selected column.
Here is the query.

```
$resource_cnt = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('prj_id, sum(amount) as amt')
->from('resources')
->where('prj_id = ' . $_POST['Resources']['prj_id'])
->queryRow();
```